# ERROR from UglifyJs Name expected

Tags: angular, uglifyjs

When i try to build an angular application using the Angular CLI with the prod flag (ng build --prod) i get this error:

> ERROR in 0.1cdedc40ae376a34d57e.chunk.js from UglifyJs Name expected
>   [0.1cdedc40ae376a34d57e.chunk.js:7923,29]

This is the tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/common": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/core": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/forms": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/http": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/router": "4.3.4",
    "core-js": "2.5.0",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "mousetrap": "1.6.1",
    "ng-block-ui": "1.0.0-beta.14",
    "ng2-smart-table-custom": "1.2.4",
    "ng2-webstorage": "1.8.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "systemjs": "0.20.17",
    "tinymce": "4.6.5",
    "zone.js": "0.8.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "4.3.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "8.0.20",
    "codelyzer": "3.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.7.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "karma-typescript": "3.0.4",
    "karma-typescript-preprocessor": "0.3.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.6.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  }
```

Any clues?, is there a known issue between any of these dependencies and uglifyJs?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, in my case it is an error in the code of one of my dependencies, something that might help you find the culprit is to add the source map flag to your angular cli build call, like this: `ng build --prod -sm`, that will give you the line number and the name of the file causing the problem.

Comment: @JeanLescure Thanks, that helped me narrow the problem to a third party library.